# How can I change the app display name build with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, application-name

I have created the app using Flutter create testapp.
Now, I want to change the app name from "testapp" to "My Trips Tracker". How can I do that?

I have tried changing from the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and it got changed, but is there a way that Flutter provides to do that?

Comment: The manifest is the only way to change the name that is shown in the Settings app and the name shown on your launcher icon.

Comment: For visual people this video will show you the whole process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05twEATiS44

Comment: Use a plugin,it's easy, fast, secure,and already tested by the comunity, the [flutter_app_name](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_name) package it's a great option, and have support for null-safety. The other recommended package is [flutter_launcher_name](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_name), but basically flutter_launcher_name don't support null safety, check the [Null safety support](https://github.com/daisuke-fukuda/flutter_launcher_name/issues/9).

Answer (score 285, accepted):

UPDATE: From the comments this answer seems to be out of date

The Flutter documentation points out where you can change the display name of your application for both Android and iOS. This may be what you are looking for:

- [Preparing an Android App for Release](https://flutter.io/android-release/)
- [Preparing an iOS App for Release](https://flutter.io/ios-release/)

**For Android**

It seems you have already found this in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as the `application` entry.

> Review the default **App Manifest** file **AndroidManifest.xml** located in
> **/android/app/src/main/** and verify the values are correct,
> especially:
>
> **application**: Edit the **android:label** in the **application** tag to reflect the final name of the
> app.

**For iOS**

See the `Review Xcode project settings` section:

> Navigate to your target’s settings in Xcode:
>
> In Xcode, open **Runner.xcworkspace** in your app’s **ios** folder.

> To view your app’s settings, select the **Runner** project in the Xcode project
> navigator. Then, in the main view sidebar, select the **Runner** target.

> Select the **General** tab. Next, you’ll verify the most important
> settings:
>
> **Display Name**: the name of the app to be displayed on the home screen
> and elsewhere.

**For Windows**

goto the windows/runner/main.cpp file and check the name in line 30:

```cpp
if (!window.Create(L"YourAPPName", origin, size)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**For Linux**

goto linux/my_application.cc edit these two lines (I never tested it)

```cpp
gtk_header_bar_set_title(header_bar, "AppName");
```

```cpp
gtk_window_set_title(window, "AppName");
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I knew the native methods to do that.
I was just curious to know if flutter handles it from a single point.

Comment: These are native methods to do that. I want to know flutter handles it from a single point or not?

Comment: @AshtonThomas I can change this but after cleaning rebuilding etc, runner app resets its value, how can I keep this?(As I understand Runner project is recreated after clean build or so)

Comment: If you change Display Name in the runner project it will stop working. It has to be ´Runner' Apparently, it is necessary to change the name and version data on the pubspeck.yaml file only, which is quite incovenient if android and ios apps have different versions or name localization

Comment: @Johnykutty Were you able to figure out? Am also having the same issue

Comment: For iOS this is incorrect. One should change the CFBundleName in Info.plist. Flutter will not find the app, as it will look for the Runner.app, and if you change it in Xcode that is no longer the case.

Comment: This answer is just wrong, at least for iOS. To change the name that is displayed under the Apps icon in iOS, I had to go to App Directory > ios > Runner, open info.plist and change the 'bundle name' from 'app' to whatever I would like to call it. That is the only thing which actually worked. Changing `Runner` in `Runner.xcworkspace` will not allow you to run the app after the next build.

Comment: I found a plugin to change display name of both at one location:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_name

Answer (score 668):

### Android

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` (located at `android/app/src/main`)

```
<application
    android:label="App Name" ...> // Your app name here
```

---

### iOS

Open `info.plist` (located at `ios/Runner`)

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App Name</string> // Your app name here
```

##### and/or

[image]

---

*Don't forget to stop and run the app again.*

Comment: For Android, this does not work. Trying to change from <OldName> to <NewName>,  the error message sais: `Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(OldName) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-32
 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-32 value=(NewName).`. What do you suggest ??

Comment: You may have more than one `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your project, you will have to open the one located at `android/app/src/main`.

Comment: This *appears* to be all sorts of broken with the latest IOS updates and/or Catalina updates and/or Flutter updates. I have no idea. Changing this now breaks the deployment as it renames the <appname>.app folder from a consistent Runner.app to whatever you put in display name, and then "flutter run" breaks. Now, if you want to change it, you name the name:<value> key in the YAML file, then do global search/replace on the package name. (sigh)

Comment: what about name in pubspec.yaml

Comment: @Fethi That's just the name of your project. For names, you'll have to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (in Android) and `info.plist` (in iOS). Flutter [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest) mention it too.

Comment: how to add space between the app name, ios info.plist doesnt support space.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad is it a better practice to define the android app name inside strings.xml instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: @HaidarMehsen Yes, you should if you're targeting different locales.

Answer (score 57):

There is a plugin called *[flutter_launcher_name](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_name)*.

Write file *pubspec.yaml*:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_name: "^0.0.1"

flutter_launcher_name:
  name: "yourNewAppLauncherName"
```

And run:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_name:main
```

You can get the same result as editing `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Info.plist`.

Comment: Nice! I'll test the plugin. But as far as I know, if you change the Display Name on the info.plist file from 'Runner', the app stops compiling. It has to be 'Runner'.

Comment: Sorry it is not working. Like Dpedrinha said, it has to be 'Runner'.

Comment: it's working for me. But i need to delete the app and reinstall it after run: `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_name:main`

Comment: There is also a plugin to replace the icon https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: The plugin was not updated for flutter 2.0 and has dependency issues

Comment: I had the followin error that went away when I removed the `flutter_launcher_name` dependency:

`Flutter – Error: ADB exited with exit code 1`

Comment: There is a paliative solution for the problem with the plugin [according to this comment](https://github.com/daisuke-fukuda/flutter_launcher_name/issues/12#issuecomment-812217297)

Comment: This plugin is no longer valid as it has not been upgraded to Flutter 2, so you will run into dependency issues. `flutter_app_name` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_name) is a nearly identical plugin but works with Flutter 2.0.

Answer (score 38):

You can change it in iOS without opening Xcode by editing the project/ios/Runner/info.plist `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>` to the String that you want as your name.

FWIW - I was getting frustrated with making changes in Xcode and Flutter, so I started committing all changes before opening Xcode, so I could see where the changes show up in the Flutter project.

Answer (score 19):

### Android

**android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:label="Display Name" // <---- HERE
```

### iOS and macOS

**ios/runner/Info.plist**

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Display Name</string> // <---- HERE
```

### Windows

**windows/runner/Runner.rc**

```
BEGIN
    VALUE "CompanyName", "com.company" "\0"
    VALUE "FileDescription", "Display Name" "\0" // <---- HERE
    VALUE "FileVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
    VALUE "InternalName", "Display Name" "\0" // <---- HERE
    VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright (C) 2023 com.company. All rights reserved." "\0"
    VALUE "OriginalFilename", "appname.exe" "\0"
    VALUE "ProductName", "Display Name" "\0" // <---- HERE
    VALUE "ProductVersion", VERSION_AS_STRING "\0"
END
```

---

**windows/CMakeLists.txt** (and not windows/runner/CMakeLists.txt)

```
set(BINARY_NAME "appname") // <---- HERE TO CHANGE OUTPUT FILE appname.exe
```

---

**windows/runner/main.cpp**

```
if (!window.Create(L"Display Name", origin, size)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

### There are several possibilities:

#### 1- The use of a package:

I suggest you to use [flutter_launcher_name](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_name) because of the command-line tool which simplifies the task of updating your Flutter app's launcher name.

**Usage:**

Add your Flutter Launcher name configuration to your *pubspec.yaml* file:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_name: "^0.0.1"

flutter_launcher_name:
  name: "yourNewAppLauncherName"
```

After setting up the configuration, all that is left to do is run the package.

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_name:main
```

If you use this package, you don't need modify file *AndroidManifest.xml* or *Info.plist*.

#### 2- Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android and `info.plist` for iOS

For **Android**, edit **only** `android:label` value in the **application** tag in file *AndroidManifest.xml* located in the folder: `android/app/src/main`

**Code:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Your Application Name"  //here
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity>
        <!--  -->
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

For **iOS**, edit **only** the value inside the **String** tag in file *Info.plist* located in the folder `ios/Runner` .

**Code:**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Your Application Name </string>  //here
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Do a `flutter clean` and restart your application if you have a problem.

Answer (score 16):

- Review the default app manifest file, `AndroidManifest.xml`, located in `<app dir>/android/app/src/main`
- Edit the `android:label` to your desired display name

Answer (score 16):

You can easily do this with [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package, It helps you to change your Flutter project's **AppName** and **BundleId** for any platform you want and it is currently supporting all the 6 platforms (Android, IOS, Linux, macOS, Windows, and Web).

- To install the package run the following command:

```
flutter pub global activate rename
```

- To rename the App, use the following command:

```
flutter pub global run rename setAppName --targets ios,android,macos,windows,linux,web --value "Your App Name"
```

**That's It!**

---

You can check the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) of the package for full details because it has some nice features to choose the target platform and more.

Comment: Great solution. I use this package for renaming projects too. 

You may need to add flutter before pub

Comment: Not working. I dont knwo why. It was working earlier.

Answer (score 11):

A few of the answers here suggest using the package `flutter_launcher_name`, but this package is no longer being maintained and will result in dependency issues within new Flutter 2.0 projects.

The plugin `flutter_app_name` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_name) is a nearly identical package that has sound null safety and will work with Flutter 2.0.

1. Set your dev dependencies and your app's name

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_app_name: ^0.1.1

flutter_app_name:
  name: "My Cool App"
```

2. Run `flutter_app_name` in your project's directory

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_app_name
```

Your launcher will now have the name of "My Cool App".

Answer (score 8):

You can change it in iOS without opening Xcode by editing file *project/ios/Runner/info.plist. Set `<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>` to the string that you want as your name.

For Android, *change* the app name from the Android folder, in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file, *android/app/src/main*. Let the android label refer to the name you prefer, for example,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <application
        android:label="test"
        // The rest of the code
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the tag `application` be closed after `android:label="test"`? Or is all of "The rest of the code" (XML) attributes?

Comment: yes it should be closed last after all the tags cuz it's the parent of all tags

Comment: this answer worked for me, setting <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key> to the new app name. other answers said set <key>CFBundleName</key> to the app name, but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the Application name, by updating the name for both Android and iOS

for **Android**

just open **AndroidManifest.xml** file by,

go to inside android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml

like this:-
[image]

so my application name is a "demo" so, I will update the label value.

same as for **iOS**
just open **Info.plist** file  by,

go to inside ios>Runner>Info.plist

like this:-
[image]

And change this string value.

Answer (score 6):

One problem is that in iOS Settings (iOS 12.x) if you change the Display Name, it leaves the app name and icon in iOS Settings as the old version.

Comment: what helped me: go to "Info" Tab and change "Bundle name".

Answer (score 5):

For Android, *change* the app name from the **Android** folder. In the *AndroidManifest.xml* file, in folder `android/app/src/main`, let the `android` label refer to the name you prefer, for example,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <application
        `android:label="myappname"`
        // The rest of the code
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Should the [backticks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick#Noun) literally be there?

Answer (score 3):

I saw indeed the manual solution (to go to IOS and Android). But I found out a plugin which enables changing name from one single location:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_name

Just do the following:
Add to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_launcher_name: "^0.0.1"
  
flutter_launcher_name:
  name: "yourNewAppLauncherName"
```

Run in Terminal:

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_name:main
```

Done.

Comment: A more recent version of this module, compatible with Flutter 2 and with null safety, is https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_name

Comment: Even newer than the published package is the repo itself: https://github.com/f-prime/flutter_app_name which includes changes to support setting the bundleId (iOS) / applicationId (android) thanks to [PR1](https://github.com/f-prime/flutter_app_name/pull/1)

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-12-21, you need to change the name [NameOfYourApp] in file *pubspec.yaml*. Then go to menu *Edit* → *Find* → *Replace in Path*, and replace all occurrences of your previous name.

Also, just for good measure, change the folder names in your *android* directory, e.g. android/app/src/main/java/com/example/*yourappname*.

Then in the console, in your app's root directory, run

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: I wonder how you put display name in pubspec with all spaces, cyrillic letters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

in case you are releasing for multi-localizations (languages).

**for Android:**

in your app folder at
**[appname]\android\app\src\main\res**
add locale folders for example:

**values-ar**

**valuse-en**

then inside each folder add a new **strings.xml** that contains the app name in that language.

for *ar*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ادارة الديون</string>
</resources>
```

for *en*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">debt management</string>
    </resources>
```

The last thing you can do is go to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file
and set the **android:label** to the new files you have created.

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**
Rename your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:label="Your App Name"
```

**Second**
Rename Your Application Name in Pubspec.yaml file
`name: Your Application Name`

**Third**
Change Your Application logo

```
flutter_icons:
   android: "launcher_icon"
   ios: true
   image_path: "assets/path/your Application logo.formate"
```

**Fourth**
Run

```
flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to automate stuff from command line like me, you can use this

```
appName="TestApp"
declare -a androidAppTypes=(
    "main"
    "debug"
    "profile"
)

# Change app name for Android
for appType in ${androidAppTypes[@]}
do
    xmlstarlet ed -L -u '/manifest/application/@android:label' -v "$appName" android/app/src/$appType/AndroidManifest.xml
done

# Change app name for Android
plutil -replace CFBundleDisplayName -string "$appName" ios/Runner/Info.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
flutter pub add rename_app
```

Provide your app name in the following way:

```
flutter pub add rename_app:main android="Android Name" ios="IOS Name" web="Web Name" mac="Mac Name" windows="Windows Name"
```

Answer (score -1):

The way of changing the name for iOS and Android is clearly mentioned in the documentation as follows:

- *[Build and release an Android app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)*
- *[Build and release an iOS app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)*

But, the case of iOS after you change the *Display Name* from [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), you are not able to run the application in the Flutter way, like `flutter run`.

Because the Flutter run expects the app name as *Runner*. Even if you change the name in Xcode, it doesn't work.

**So, I fixed this as follows:**

Move to the location on your Flutter project, *ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj*, and find and replace all instances of your new name with *Runner*.

Then everything should work in the `flutter run` way.

**But don't forget to change the name display name on your next release time. Otherwise, the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29) rejects your name.**