# How to change the name of Flutter Application?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application

I just made a Flutter app following the instructions of [this page](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2/#0), and I googled how to change the name of the application, and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353199/how-to-change-the-app-display-name-build-with-flutter). But I can't change the name of the application from the manifest file. Initially `android:name` is `io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication`. I changed that to `Startup Namer`, and it gave the error

```
error: attribute 'android:name' in <application> tag must be a valid Java class name.
```

How to reslove this error and change the name?

Comment: Have you tried without the space between `Startup` and `Namer`?

Comment: I tried it now, it still gave the same error. However, I saw another parameter `android:label` and changed it to `Startup Namer`, and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the app display name build with flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353199/how-to-change-the-app-display-name-build-with-flutter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The displayed name of the application is identified by the attribute `android:label`. You should change that one instead of `android:name`.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android and `info.plist` for iOS**

For **Android**, edit **only** `android:label` value in the **application** tag in file *AndroidManifest.xml* located in the folder: `android/app/src/main`

**Code:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Your Application Name"  //here
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity>
        <!--  -->
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For **iOS**, edit **only** the value inside the **String** tag in file *Info.plist* located in the folder `ios/Runner` .

**Code:**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Your Application Name </string>  //here
</dict>
</plist>
```

Do a `flutter clean` and restart your application if you have a problem.

Comment: In addition to this, for iOS I also needed to update `CFBundleDisplayName`