# Flutter: Build variant (flavor) with different package name (applicationId)

Tags: flutter, build-variant

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631934/can-a-secondary-branch-pull-changes-from-branch-master-locally), and according to the comments I have to use multiple configs file, which is like multiple flavors for android. I have seen other questions and answers, but this is not duplicate, since none of them required changing the applicationId.
but in my case I need to change the applicationId, which is the package name for example:

first build: com.client1.AppName1

second build: com.client2.AppName2

third build: com.client3.AppName3

and also I need to specify a different google-services.json for each build, since the applicationId is changing (because when i was trying to rename manually, I always faced the issue with services.json throwing an error because of the package name).
can this be configurable? or will I need to create a different folder for each flavor?

P.S: the code base is the same, only colors, application name, launch icon, and most important is applicationId and google-services json, will change.