# How can I remove an underscore from my app name in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Could someone kindly tell me how I could remove the underscore from my app name.

When I use a simulator, or a real phone (iPhone or android), the name in the screen appears as "my_app_name" - which looks odd.

I tried to change the name in the .yaml file - but it won't allow a space in the name.

```
name: my_app_name
```

That cannot be changed. It won't accept spaces.

What is the way around this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean on the top of your app screen or below the launcher icon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the app display name build with flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353199/how-to-change-the-app-display-name-build-with-flutter)

Answer (score 8):

**For Android:**

Go to: `android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` and change:

```
android:label="my_app_name"
```

to

```
android:label="My App Name"
```

**For IOS:**

Go to: `ios\Runner\info.plist` and change:

```
<string>my_app_name</string>
```

to

```
<string>My App Name</string>
```

Comment: Small note on the above you might find you have to run `flutter clean` before trying `flutter run` again

Answer (score 0):

In Android go to manifest file and find:

```
lable: your desired name
```

In iOS/Runner/Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>yourAppName</string>
```

Comment: Now that's interesting. Because I went there and I changed the name, yet it now prints my app out as myNameApp - so it is better, but still doesn't work