# How to change the app name and app icon after installing the app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My Requirement is to **change the app name and app icon programmatically after installing the application** in flutter.

Using the flutter dynamic icon package :https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon we can change only the dynamic icon

```
import 'package:flutter_dynamic_icon/flutter_dynamic_icon.dart'; if (await FlutterDynamicIcon.supportsAlternateIcons) {
await FlutterDynamicIcon.setAlternateIconName("photos");
```

Is there is any best solution to achieve my requirement?. please guide.

Comment: Check this for name https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354353/12402503, Check this for icon https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: @FederickJonathan  The links you have shared give a solution on how to change the name and icon before install. But my requirement is to change the app name and icon after installing the application programmatically.

Comment: any solution? @Tester12

Answer (score 0):

While the app icon can be changed dynamically for use-cases like dynamic icon for Clock and Calendar apps, the app name can't be changed during run-time. The app name on Android is configured in the Manifest file and on iOS, it's on the InfoPlist file. This can be changed by modifying these files and pushing an update for your app.