# How can I change the name of my Flutter app for M1 Macs?

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, apple-m1

I have [an app](https://inspiral.nathanfriend.io/) built with Flutter that is available for M1 Macs.

In the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/inspiral-gear-art/id1558340425), I've named the app "Inspiral - Gear Art".

However, when installed on an M1 Mac, the name of the app is "inspiral":

[image: screenshot of the app on an M1]

How can I change the name of this app for M1 Mac users?

Comment: nice app there !

Comment: @Fattie Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that my app's name on iOS devices was showing as "Inspiral" (capitalized), but now that I look closer, it's actually rendering as "inspiral" (lowercase) there, too ‍♂️

So I believe the fix is the same for a regular iOS app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039224/1063392

(Disclaimer: I haven't yet had a chance to verify this.)