# I want to change the name of my app when multitab is pressed in

Tags: flutter, dart

I have changed the name of my app and its all good. On my homeScreen or in settings it is shown fine, but when i press multitab, the one which shows all ur running apps on your phone i dont see my app name but my project name. Or at least i think its that. Here is a photo of my app icon in home screen[icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnsS2.jpg)
And here is how is shown when multitab is opened[multitab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8cMF.jpg)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448447/10746978) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your app name, or whatever title that you want, for the `title` parameter of `MaterialApp()`.

Like this,

```dart
runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: "title",
    home: FirstPage(),
  ));
```

This should solve your issue, do mark this as answer if it solves so that it helps others too..

Comment: that worked thanks... i had like 4 different material apps because i have different roles , and i changed the title property in 2 of them but forgot in the others... anyway thanks bro.