# How can I change the name and the logo of google_sign_in with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm using google_sign_in + firebase to authenticate users via their google accounts in my flutter application.
I don't want my users to see the panel like the image below:
(It has the flutter logo and my project name! But I want to put the app logo and a customized name instead.)

**Image:**
[image: Image:]

Comment: I found the solution in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353199/how-can-i-change-the-app-display-name-build-with-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided image in your question there is no way to edit the icon and name of the application manually or by code in the mentioned screenshot, the only way is to change the entire project icon and project name which is guided as follows.

**To change project name on Android**

Open AndroidManifest.xml (located at android/app/src/main)

```
<application
      android:label="App Name" ...> // Your app name here
```

**To change project name on iOS**

Open info.plist (located at ios/Runner)

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>App Name</string> // Your app name here
```

Don't forget to run

```
flutter clean
```

**To change the project icon use the following flutter plugin or watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9ChjwrZqns&t=55s)**

```
flutter_launcher_icons
```